# Importing tensorflow in idle throws error: DLL load failed

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-idle

My python version is 3.6. I successfully installed tensorflow, but when I imported in idle it gives error as following :
[image]

Comment: Can you post the text of the error instead of a picture?

Comment: Are you sure you installed tensorflow in the same python environment that you are running your REPL in?

Comment: Your REPL's python seems to be located at `C:\Users\sushi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36`. Where is the python located that you used to install tensorflow?

Comment: C:\Users\sushi>where python
C:\Users\sushi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe
C:\Users\sushi\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe

this is where my python is installed

Comment: I installed it with cmd prompt

Comment: SAME ERROR WHILE IMPORTING ON CMD PROMPT

Comment: What was the exact command you used to install tensorflow and what command are you using to test the import on the cmd prompt?

Comment: Assuming you installed with `pip install tensorflow`, what does `where pip` give you? If it's a different location than your python install, you might try `python -m pip install tensorflow`.

Comment: yes i used pip install tensorflow

Comment: C:\Users\sushi>where pip
C:\Users\sushi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\pip.exe

location of pip is also same

Comment: python -m pip install tensorflow 
this command also says requirment already satisfied

Comment: Actually, looking at the stack trace again, it looks like the error is to do with something in google protobuf.

Comment: If you started python on a command line without starting IDLE, and `import tensorflow` gave the same error, then the error has nothing to do with IDLE and should not be tagged

Comment: What should I do now..????

Comment: Does your system has 32-bit python or 64-bit python?